# C# convert Numbers to Exponential form in specific format

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, exponential, exp

I want to use the string formatter to present decimal value with combination value which is int and exp without lost any information of the double. Example:

```
12,35 => 1235 exp -2
12,359 => 12359 exp -3
123,5967 => 1235967 exp -4 
130 => 13 exp 1
1300 => 13 exp 2
```

I tried to use

```
string.Format("{0:######E0}", value)
```

But this add additional 0 values into the int number value:

```
12,35 => 12350000 exp -6. But I want to be 12345 exp -2
```

Can you give me some suggestion how I can pass my examples?

Comment: Would building a function help u? or u need something inline? I've tested for example Regex.Replace(string.Format("{0:0.###E+0}", 12.35), "0*E", " exp ") but with E formatter it goes like 1.235 exp +1 so for sure with this approach u can't get 1235 exp -2. I think only something custom build would do it.

Comment: string.Format("{0:#####E0}", 12.35) will return 1235E-2 (What I want). But I don't know what will be the value and if I use more # to catch all possible values it add additional 0. string.Format("{0:########E0}", 12.35) will produce 1235000E-5. But I want to be 1235E-2.